# Maximum & minimum principle for harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded, connected set and $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline\Omega)$ a harmonic function on $\Omega$. Then $\min \lbrace u(x) | x \in \partial \Omega \rbrace \leq u(x) \leq \max \lbrace u(x) | x \in \partial \Omega \rbrace, \forall x \in \Omega$.

I tried to prove this using the weak form of the maximum (minimum) priciple which says:
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded, connected set and $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline\Omega)$ such that $0 \leq \Delta u(x)$ ($\Delta u(x) \leq 0$) on $\Omega$. Then one and oly one of the following holds:

i) $\max \lbrace u(x) | x\in \overline{\Omega} \rbrace = \max \lbrace u(x)|x \in \partial \Omega\rbrace$ (respectively $\min \lbrace u(x) | x\in \overline{\Omega} \rbrace\min \lbrace u(x)|x \in \partial \Omega\rbrace$).

ii) $u$ is constant on $\Omega$.

I can use the principles since $u$ is harmonic but I don't know how I could show that $u$ is not constant on $\Omega$. If I show this, then the conclusion will follow easily.

Comment: But if $u$ is constant, your statement should be trivially true.

Comment: I only know that $u$ is constant on $\Omega$ but why that constant is smaller (higher) than that maximum(minimum) on the boundary?

Comment: But if your function is constant inside and continuous up to the boundary, it should be constant in $\overline{\Omega}$.